# Twitter BS - toggle class on <LI> when carousel changes

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to build a portfolio that uses the carousel. 
I'm using the following as a way to navigate to certain elements in the carousel:

```
<ul id="portfolionav" class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="" id="carousel-ux"><a href="#myCarousel" data-toggle="pill">UX | UI</a></li>
<li class="" id="carousel-vd"><a href="#myCarousel" data-toggle="pill">Visual Design</a></li>
<li class="" id="carousel-web"><a href="#myCarousel" data-toggle="pill">Web</a></li>   
<li class="" id="carousel-mobile"><a href="#myCarousel" data-toggle="pill">Mobile</a></li>
<li class="" id="carousel-corpid"><a href="#myCarousel" data-toggle="pill">Identity</a></li>
```

What I am trying to do is apply the active class on an LI tag when a specific element in the carousel is reached. For example, when the carousel slides to element #5, the active class needs to apply to the "mobile" LI tag, and be removed from any of the other LI tags.

Can anyone please give me a idea on how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had been playing around with a similar idea, based on a post i found here: http://forrst.com/posts/Adding_pagination_to_bootstrap_carousel-ULn

My implementation here, with slide titles rather than just bullets:

http://jsfiddle.net/64qK2/

By tweaking the javascript, you could set the active class on the LI item rather than the link, and add nav stylings.

/Mark